Connected via AP mode. But No Internet
I've got a RPi4B which runs BerryOS and I've converted my wifi to AP MODE for 2.4GHz( usb adapter) 5GHz (internal) access points. The odd thing about this is that while my older devices (iOS 13, Android 7) can connect to the 5GHz and 2.4GHz and access the internet, my newer devices (Windows 11, Android 10) can connect to the AP but there is NO internet.
I'm using cloud-init and netplan to configure the bridge and eth0 interfaces
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
bridges:
  br0:
    interfaces:
      - eth0
    dhcp4: no 
    dhcp6: yes 
    addresses:
      - 192.168.1.197/24
    routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.1.1
    nameservers:
      addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        - 192.168.1.1
    parameters:
      stp: false
      forward-delay: 0
    accept-ra: true

while using cloud-init to handle the wifi ( netplan can't config ap mode wifis)
write_files:
  - path: /etc/hostapd/wlan0.conf
    content: |
      interface=wlan0
      driver=nl80211
      ssid=xxxxx
      hw_mode=a
      channel=0
      wmm_enabled=1
      ieee80211n=1
      ieee80211ac=1
      # ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]
      # vht_capab=[VHT160][SHORT-GI-80][SHORT-GI-160]
      macaddr_acl=0
      auth_algs=1
      ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
      wpa=2
      country_code=JM
      wpa_passphrase=xxxx
      wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
      wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
      bridge=br0
  - path: /etc/hostapd/wlan1.conf
    content: |
      interface=wlan1
      driver=nl80211
      ssid=xxxx
      hw_mode=g
      ieee80211n=1
      channel=6
      wmm_enabled=1
      macaddr_acl=0
      auth_algs=1
      ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
      wpa=2
      wpa_passphrase=xxxx
      wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
      wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
      bridge=br0
      country_code=CB
  - path: /etc/hostapd/hostapd
    content: |
      DAEMON_OPTS=" -dd T /var/log/hostapd.log"
      DAEMON_CONF=""
  - path: /etc/systemd/network/10-wlan1.network
    content: |
      [Match]
      Name=wlan1

      [Network]
      Bridge=br0
runcmd:
  # Install required packages
  - rkill unblock wlan
  - sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
  - sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
  - sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  - sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
  - sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  - sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
  - sudo netfilter-persistent save
  - echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
  - sudo sysctl -p
  - sudo systemctl unmask hostapd@wlan0
  - sudo systemctl unmask hostapd@wlan1
  - sudo systemctl enable hostapd@wlan0
  - sudo systemctl enable hostapd@wlan1
  - sudo systemctl start hostapd@wlan0
  - sudo systemctl start hostapd@wlan1

the br0(bridge DHCP upstream) to allow wlan0 and wlan1 to access eth0 (internet)
I'm not sure what is the cause or where to start to look?

Is it a routing problem?
Is it an ipv6 address issue?
is it a channel problem( all devices are in the same place/ proximity)

